# Search function in a dialog

Tags: android, user-interface, material-design

How can I implement a search bar in a pop-up dialog, like in the attached screenshot (from app "Skit")?[image]

I don't need the logic, just UI.

Comment: You use a DialogFragment with a custom layout file and show it as a dialog

Comment: That's just designing the EditText...